# why the error: fatal error: Array index out of range? [swift]

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

Please find error location in the below image :

[image: error location screenshot]

The number of values in tripOption will change in each request.

There a logic problem in the code where the tripOption for example outputs just 2 values.. but the loop keeps going and says array out of index.. i have no idea how to fix this issue.

```
 var arrayOfFlights : [FlightDataModel] = [FlightDataModel]()

        if json != nil {

            //insert airline data into arrayOfFlights
            if let myJSON = json as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let trips = myJSON["trips"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if let data = trips["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

                        if let carriers = data["carrier"] as? [[String:String]] {
                            for (index, carrierName) in enumerate(carriers) {

                                var myFlight = FlightDataModel(airline: carrierName["name"] as String!, price:nil)
                                self.arrayOfFlights.append(myFlight)

                                println("\(self.arrayOfFlights[index].airline!)")

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if var tripOptions = trips["tripOption"] as? [[String:String]] {

                        for (index, tripOption) in enumerate(tripOptions) {

                            self.arrayOfFlights[index].price = tripOption["saleTotal"] as String!

                          println("price \(self.arrayOfFlights[index].price!)")

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

---

parameteers in url jsjon request:

```
var parameters = [
    "request": [
        "slice": [
            [
                "origin": from,
                "destination": to,
                "date": when
            ]
        ],

        "passengers": [
            "adultCount": 1,
            "infantInLapCount": 0,
            "infantInSeatCount": 0,
            "childCount": 0,
            "seniorCount": 0
        ],

        "solutions": 5,
        "refundable": false

    ]
]
```

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts; that's not fair to those that put in work to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to access an element in `arrayOfFlights` with an index greater than its `size - 1`.

Comment: please see edit. How do I change it to only access its size, when the size changes at every request... sometimes tripOption has 3 values, sometimes 10. It depends on the request.

Comment: The for loop will go on only till it iterates over all the values in `tripOptions` array. Is the size of `arrayOfFlights` that big?

Comment: not big. but theres no set value for tripOptions. For each request the value might hold 3 values or 5 or any up to 120

Answer (score 0):

```
// index > no of existing elements in the array
self.arrayOfFlights[index].price = tripOption["saleTotal"] as String!
```

Maybe you are trying to push new elements into an empty array?

```
self.arrayOfFlightPrices.append(tripOption["saleTotal"] as String!)
```

Comment: Hey Mikael. I edited the code to show the full manipulation of json data into a data structure. What do you think now?

Comment: Ok I see. It looks like you get a number of flights from `data["carrier"]`. But that this number of flights are less then the number of `tripOptions`. Are you sure the JSON is supposed to have one `tripOption` for each `carrier`? Or is there some other way to map carrier <-> tripOptions. A key maybe? If you could print the Json, there might be some key for each tripOption?

Comment: example output:  Jetstar Airways Pty Limited            
Virgin Australia International Airlines       
price AUD126.22          
price AUD135.22        
fatal error: Array index out of range

Comment: in the json request, i hardcoded json to only give out 5 solutions.. and here teh request only outputs 2, cause only 2 exist.  so maybe somewhere there is a problem? Is there a way to change the logic

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your code and perhaps use the first iteration of the results to ensure you don't go out of bounds. Something LIKE this:

```
var arrayOfFlights : [FlightDataModel] = [FlightDataModel]()

    if let data = json as? NSDictionary {

        if let carriers = data.valueForKeyPath("trips.data.carrier") as? NSArray {
            for (index, carrier) in enumerate(carriers) {
                var myFlight = FlightDataModel(airline: carrier["name"] as String!, price:nil)
                arrayOfFlights.append(myFlight)
            }
        }

        if let trips = data.valueForKey("trips") as? NSArray where arrayOfFlights.count > 0 {
            for (index, carrier) in enumerate(arrayOfFlights) {
                carrier.price = trips.objectAtIndex(index)["saleTotal"] as String!                    
            }
        }
    }
```